# Where is the back button graphic Apple uses in the navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to add code to the back button presented in UINavigationController.  But, I want the back button to look identical to what Apple presents.

I have this all setup to use my graphic in the leftBarButton, but am unable to get the graphic to look perfect.  To that end, is there a way that I can use the internal iOS back button in my own custom button?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the navigation bar's back button is not very customizable. There is no simple way to access this image.

If you're familiar with Sketch or Photoshop, I suggest you take a screenshot of the back button and trace your image over the exact location.

If you can't do this, you technically can access the back buttons image through some minor UI manipulation. You'll have to first have a back button which is on screen. Once you know it's on screen, such as in your `viewDidAppear`, you'll want to look through the subviews of your `leftBarButtonItem`. One way you can do this is by calling `navigationBar.subviews` and navigating until the view. Another way is to expose the items target view.

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    var targetView: UIView? {
        guard let view = value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else {
            return nil
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Now you can call `leftBarButtonItem.targetView.subviews`. Your for-loop would look something like,

```
for subview in leftBarButtonItem.targetView.subviews {
    if let imageView = subview as? UIImageView {
        self.image = imageView?.image
    }
}
```

All of this is pseudo code and untested. Typically UIKit will use the standard classes (such as `UIImageView`) when building their views. However in older classes, they have been known to draw images manually. So if there is no image, you can always resort to taking a snapshot of the view with the arrow.

`view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)`

Once you have your image / view, you'll save it in a property (most likely in your custom navigation controller) and then you'll have access to it whenever you push new view controllers.